# Create new android project with out Fragment activity in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

After the ADT update in eclipse whenever I create a new project for android a default fragment activity is created. How to get to create simple activity always?

I don't want to downgrade the ADT.

Is this possible? any work around?

Comment: a better solution is to delete all the unnecessary codes from the activity
move the contents of the fragment.xml to activity.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an Activity is simply a Java class, just accept the defaults the ADT gives you during the initial creation of your project. Create your project, then manually:

**1.** Delete all the `class` and `layout` files in your project.

**2.** Create your `Java` class files extending `Activity` (in your desired packages).

**3.** Create XML layout files (in the `res/layout` folder).

**4.** 'Wire-up' your Java class files and XML layout files using `setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_ID)` in the `onCreate()` methods.

**5.** Done!

**EDIT**

Remember to Register your Activities in the Manifest manually as well.

Answer (score 2):

The latest ADT plugins are made in such a way that if you create any simple project you will always get the `FragmentActivity` not a simple `Activity`. And you can not change it.

In new ADT itself there is Blank Activity that is **defined with an actionbar and optional navigational elements such as tabs or horizontal swipe**.

If you want to create simple activity in your project then you can simply create class and extends Activity into it, this is the only way now. Or you can change the `Fragment` with `Activity` simply by changing code only.